# Visual Studio graphic modules designer

Tags: visual-studio, code-generation, codefluent

I want to create a smart and easy way to produce and generate code automatically.

It's not easy to explain, but what I want to do is something like what codefluent software (http://www.softfluent.com/) does. So design graphically a model and what is generated is a collection of classes in according with some rules defined for my context. Otherwise, also a tool like Telerik which is integrate in Visual Studio and through a custom menu it's possible to manage particular behaviours of the application.

I know that my request is not clear and so general, but also my acutal ideas are in an embrional state. I see that Visual Studio support a DSL SDK (vsvmsdk) which permits to specify and design an own language. But I can't understand if it is exactly what I need.

Anyone can suggest me a different tool or maybe a documentation about what I can do in Visual Studio to reach my goal?

Answer (score 0):

CodeFluent Entities is a custom-made tool, it's not relying on any 3rd party software. The graphical surface is using WPF with special algorithms and specific lightweight treeviews. (disclaimer: I work for this company, and I helped develop that software).

That being said, if you want to quickly develop something, you could indeed start with the http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vsvmsdk you mention (VSVMSDK is the successor of the DSL SDK, aka 'DSL Tools'). It has the big advantage of being free. Note however the future of this component at Microsoft is unclear, as they seem to prefer 'Code-first' over 'Model-first' now.

Comment: So the only way is to study VSVMSDK. No way .... any suggestion on best tutorials or guide to understand the potentials of this tools and to understand if it is what i need? MSDN is not so clear to start from the zero point (so for my situation -_-' ). Thank you